# TreeView with items that have nodes icons and without icons

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, treeview, wtl

I have a TreeView control in a Windows C++ application that **has an ImageList set**.
I am trying to insert an node that **does not have icon** (without `TVIF_IMAGE` flag) but the icon is still displayed.

```
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { 0 };
    tvis.hParent = hParent;
    tvis.hInsertAfter = hInsertAfter;
    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
    tvis.item.pszText = (LPTSTR) lpszItem;
    tvis.item.iImage = 0;
    tvis.item.iSelectedImage = 0;
    tvis.item.state = nState;
    tvis.item.stateMask = nStateMask;
    tvis.item.lParam = lParam;
    ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tvis);
```

Is that possible/ supported ?

Comment: I think your question is a better candidate for MFC and Visual C++ tags.

Comment: Include a blank icon in the image list and select that one.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is you are inserting an item with [default] image 0. You not only need `-1`, but you also need `TVIF_IMAGE`:

```
    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE;
    tvis.item.iImage = -1;
```

Here is the effect of this change compared you your snippet ([source code](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/TreeViewIcon/MainDlg.h#L46)):

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. It worked for you ? I am asking because I want to know if is smth related to styles or so

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the image flag to -1 rather than 0;